Installing Ubuntu 24.04 alongside Windows - partition not found
I've got a Windows 11 setup, and I've just installed a new SSD to install Linux on, which I'd like to be dual-boot with Windows.
My disks are as follows:

nvme0n1 : 1TB SSD partitioned for windows Boot Manager and C:
nvme2n1 : 2TB SSD with single NTFS partition (D:)
nvme1n1 : 2TB SSD (new SSD) was initially un-partitioned, but now has an empty Ext4 partition on
sda1 and sda2 : Both 8TB spinning disks, mirrored in Windows (E:)

I would like to get to the stage where I can keep my current Windows setup, and also have Linux on nvme1n1 with Grub as my bootloader
When going through the installation for Ubuntu 24.04, I get to the "Disk setup" section, which gives me the options of:

Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager
Erase disk and install Ubuntu
Manual installation

My initial feeling was that I should take the first of these options. However, on the next page it asks me which partition I want to use, and only gives me the option of nvme2n1p2, which is my D: drive in Windows, or nvme0n1p3, which is my C: drive. I don't have the option to install onto nvme1n1, which is the new SSD I've installed.
I feel like Manual installation may be the way to go for this, but I'm not comfortable enough to be confident in here to ensure that I don't wipe my Windows installation of leave it inaccessible.
When I do go to the Manual installation page, it shows the disks, but doesn't show any partitions under nvme1n1. This image shows the installation window next to the Disks tool.

I could create a new partition on nvme1n1 from the installation tool, but would I need to create multiple partitions for swap, etc. And to ensure that I'm not overwriting the Windows boot manager, or at least ensuring that Grub will still be able to boot into Windows.
Here's a screenshot of my naive thoughts on what I should do, but I feel I'm missing some additional partitions that I'd need

Any help here would be much appreciated. Either with how to use the Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager section of the installer (to get it to install to a new SSD) or how to use the Manual installation section to get the same result.

Best not to use Windows to initialize drive. It automatically adds a Windows reserved partition as that is required for Windows before first NTFS partition with boot files. But you will never need that. You want gpt partition for UEFI. And an ESP - efi system partition (first partition), and / (root). If large partition / best not if full drive. You do not have to have swap partition as now swap file is default. If you create swap partition in advance use 4.1GB and put it at end of drive so out of way. Then you can use remain space as /home or data partition(s). You can leave unallocated also.

I figured out what was not working.
If I took the new SSD and initialised it in Windows first, it was then a fresh disk with no partitions.
Next time I tried the Ubuntu installation, it just used that one automatically, as it was seeing a decent amount of unpartitioned space to use.

Why you dont use Vmware workstation pro and use both? On the left monitor I have Ubuntu, on the right monitor windows.
